# Problems with Pandas.pivot_table and converting dataset from one form to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataset

I have a dataset which is in the following form:

```
Measure_name             name        Measure_value

housing_price            Bob             380000
housing_price            Alice           270000
housing_price            Dave            140000 
Salary                   Bob              30000
Salary                   Alice            40000
Salary                   Dave             35000
Family_members           Bob                2
Family_members           Alice              4
Family_members           Dave               1
```

I am trying to convert in the following form using python and pandas:

```
name        housing_price    Salary     Family_members
Bob             380000       30000           2
Alice           270000       40000           4
Dave            140000       35000           1
```

I searched a lot and tried pandas.pivot_table() but couldn't figure it out as it was giving weird results of all sorts and documentation wasn't clear at all. I tried:

```
dataset.pivot_table( columns=['Measure_name'], values = 'Measure_values')
```

But it just gives out a single row output.

Can someone please tell me the correct way to do it? Thank you so much for your help. I am very grateful.

Comment: Use `dataset.pivot_table(index='name',  columns='Measure_name', values = 'Measure_values')`

Comment: There is missing `index='name'`

Comment: Oh no!! Can't believe I missed it. Thanks. It solved it immediately.